# Equivalence of correlated DATEADD intervals

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there any difference between the following statements?

`SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, @SomeInteger * 12, @SomeDate)`

`SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, @SomeInteger, @SomeDate)`

In other words, are there any cases in which they would yield different results for the same value of `@SomeInteger` and `@SomeDate`?

I ran a quick test via the following:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM dbo.DimDate dd
WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 12, dd.Date) <> DATEADD(YEAR, 1, dd.Date)
```

which returned zero records, but that's far from proving the two statements are equivalent.

The `computer scalar` execution plan component has the exact same cost in both queries, but the `ScalarOperator` definitions are different - it would appear that the Query Optimizer is not converting one statement into another.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case they are equivalent behaviors even though the `ScalarOperator` definitions are different. This is because in other cases they can't be swapped. Think about:

- `datediff` in days, which depends on which month and also must account for leap year.
- `datediff` in seconds which will be non-deterministic when there is a leap second.
- etc.

SQL Server doesn't gain any advantage changing one scalar operator's definition to look more like another one's. What would be the benefit? If you said `WHERE column = 4 * 5` wouldn't it be confusing if the scalar operator said `WHERE column = 2 * 10`? Even if you have another query somewhere that uses `2 * 10`?

In other words, if you said `DATEADD(MONTH, n*12, ...` I see no reason at all for SQL Server to change that expression to `DATEADD(YEAR, n, ...` just because we all happen to know that there are 12 months in a year. You asked for a delta by months, not years, so that's what the expression should show.

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for the answer! Do you have any source/code that indicates that ```DATEADD(MONTH, @n*12...``` is always identical to ```DATEADD(YEAR, @n...```?

Comment: @Cowthulhu No, but what would be the point of proving that? I also don't have any source/code that proves that dateadd(minute,60) is identical to dateadd(hour,1), even if I don't know off-hand of any edge cases where they would differ.

Comment: I guess that's sort of the point of the question - apologies if it was ambiguous! Lines 1-3 of my question were what I was aiming to "resolve". Edited my question to clear it up - added the fourth line.

Comment: I understand the question you're asking, I just don't understand the point, and I find it very hard to prove that no counter-example exists. It's like proving there are no bears in the forest just because you haven't seen any yet today.